# Removing the specific arguments

Tags: javascript, filter, arguments, default-arguments

I tried to remove some words according to the passing variable.

However, I wrote two versions of code which have minor different!

And they resulted in different kinds of output which I don't understand why!

So I need u guys help, and big big thanks for u guys!

> This function will be accepting the different numbers of variables,
>
> which might be ( [arr],1,2 ) or ( [arr],1,2,8,9...) etc,
>
> and remove the the variable in the first array according to the passing numbers.
>
> For example: destroyer ( [1, 2, 3, 4], 2, 3 ) --> output should be [1,4]
>
> And here is my code. ( Notice the minor difference with bold fonts! )

```
function destroyer(arr) {
    for ( var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++ ){
        arr = arguments[0].filter(function(value){
        if( value == arguments[i]){
          return false;
        }else{
          return true;
        }
      }); 
    }
  return arr;
}
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

> The output will be [1,2,3,1,2,3], which means  **value == arguments[i]**    doesn't work. However,

```
function destroyer(arr) {
    for ( var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++ ){
        filter = arguments[i];
        arr = arguments[0].filter(function(value){
        if( value == filter){
          return false;
        }else{
          return true;
        }
      }); 
    }
  return arr;
}
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

> This version works perfectly showing me [1,1].
>
> So what's going wrong with the first version??? Thank you!!

Comment: May I suggest a cleaner alternative to your code - https://jsfiddle.net/2zm32uom/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the first one is that `arguments` applies to the `.filter()` callback function (the closest function scope, not the parent function scope) so `arguments[i]` is not what you want it to be.

You could copy those arguments into an actual array which you could then refer to from the `.filter()` callback.

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    for ( var i = 0; i < args.length; i++ ){
        arr = arr.filter(function(value){
        if( value == args[i]){
          return false;
        }else{
          return true;
        }
      }); 
    }
  return arr;
}
var a = destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);

// show output
document.write(JSON.stringify(a));
```

---

Personally, I'd suggest a bit simpler version:

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return arr.filter(function(value) {
        return args.indexOf(value) === -1;
    });
}
var a = destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);

// show output
document.write(JSON.stringify(a));
```

---

Which, can be written simpler in ES6 using the spread operator:

```js
function destroyer(arr, ...args) {
    return arr.filter(function(value) {
        return args.indexOf(value) === -1;
    });
}
var a = destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);

// show output
document.write(JSON.stringify(a));
```

---

Or, if you prefer even shorter ES6 notation and want to use the new `Array.prototype.includes()`:

```js
function destroyer(arr, ...args) {
    return arr.filter(value => !args.includes(value));
}
var a = destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);

document.write(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Comment: Haha, I was just getting ready to post the second version you posted _verbatim_ (well, I used `Array.from(arguments);`, but other than that...). Cheers!

Comment: @RobM. - I added an ES6 version too.

Comment: if you're going ES2015 ... `return arr.filter(value => !~args.indexOf(value))` ... or ... `return arr.filter(value => !args.includes(value))`

Comment: or `return arr.filter(value => !args.includes(value))` now that we have `Array.includes`. Very nice answer though @jfriend00, if I had two upvotes to give, you would have both. hahah, now @JaromandaX is beating me to things too, maybe it's time for bed...

Comment: one line FTW - `var destroyer = (arr, ...args) => arr.filter(value => !args.includes(value));` ... @RobM. that sounds like a bit of a backhanded comment :p

Comment: @RobM. - My last option now includes both your additions.  I'll leave it as a normal function definition though.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like that in an es6 version:

```
function destroyer( arr, ...elem ) {
    return arr.reduce( ( prev, next, index ) =>  elem.includes( arr[index] ) ? prev : prev.concat(next)  , [])
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping!! @Avraam Mavrids